# Spring boot MockMvc tests returning 403 with post() only

Tags: spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I'm trying to run a MockMcv in a post method but i'm always getting a 403 error.

I am attempting to test a post method using MockMvc, but each time I execute the test, I receive a 403 error. On the other hand, I have another test that uses the get() method and it runs successfully without any issues.

**--- TEST CASE ---**

```
@WebMvcTest(CarrinhoController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class CarrinhoControllerResponseErrorTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CarrinhoMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private BuscarCarrinhoUC buscarCarrinhoUC;


    // THIS DONT WORK
    @WithMockUser
    @Test
    public void VL001() throws Exception {
        String json = "{" +
                "    'itens': [{ 'nome': 'Smartphone', 'valor_unidade': 1 }]," +
                "    'pessoa_fisica': { 'cpf': '286693401610' }," +
                "    'expira_em': '2099-01-01T00:00:00-03:00'" +
                "}";

        mockMvc.perform(post("/carrinho").content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.code").value("VL-001"));
    }


    // THIS WORK
    @WithMockUser
    @Test
    public void deveRetornarNotFoundCasoNaoExista() throws Exception {
        String codigo = "2956712b-045f-4375-8da9-181ff7a0dbc4";
        when(buscarCarrinhoUC.perform(codigo))
                .thenThrow(RecursoNaoEncontradoException.codigoCarrinho(codigo));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/carrinho/{codigo}", codigo))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message").value("Carrinho com código '2956712b-045f-4375-8da9-181ff7a0dbc4' não encontrado."));
    }

}
```

**--- CONTROLLER ---**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/carrinho")
public class CarrinhoController {


    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity criar(@RequestBody @Valid CarrinhoInput input) {
        // ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/{codigo}")
    public ResponseEntity buscar(@PathVariable String codigo) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The **application-test.properties** only have `cors.origin=*`

**--- Stacktrace ---**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /carrinho
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Length:"153"]
             Body = {    'itens': [{ 'nome': 'Smartphone', 'valor_unidade': 1 }],    'pessoa_fisica': { 'cpf': '286693401610' },    'expira_em': '2099-01-01T00:00:00-03:00'}
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@f59da34, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Forbidden
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400> but was:<403>
Expected :400
Actual   :403
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: always a good practive to use slashes on the end of endpoints, probably is that the issue